# Datalog with negation in Z3 using Pure SMT-LIB2

Tags: z3

I'm trying to write this Datalog program in Z3:

```
p :- r.
q :- \r.
```

As per [this tutorial](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/fixedpoints), I wrote:

```
(set-logic HORN)
(declare-const p Bool)
(declare-const q Bool)
(declare-const r Bool)

(assert (=> r p))
(assert (=> (not r) q))

(assert r)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

But `check-sat` yields `unknown`.  How come ?

Removing the rule defining q yields `sat`.

Comment: This example seems to work in the [online Z3 editor](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/Ez40) when I remove `(set-logic HORN)`.

Comment: Yes, but the semantic is not the same.